# how to handle change state inside array in reactJS? (using antd design for the Select element)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, antd

I just new to using `reactJS`, and I want to ask how I handle changes that occur in a state based on an index / element inside array.

I know this has been asked a lot before and the best way is to use spread syntax. but how do you use it in my case. (I am using `antd` design for the Select element)
Thanks.

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/3yoxzm4ql5

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Table} from 'reactstrap';
import {Row,Col,Input,Select} from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';

const Option = Select.Option;

class OrderBooksForm extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            rows: [{
                brandName: '',
                titleName: '',
                bookClass: '',
                firstStock: '',
                editAmount: '',
                difference: '',
            }, {
                brandName: '',
                titleName: '',
                bookClass: '',
                firstStock: '',
                editAmount: '',
                difference: '',
            }, {
                brandName: '',
                titleName: '',
                bookClass: '',
                firstStock: '',
                editAmount: '',
                difference: '',
            }, {
                brandName: '',
                titleName: '',
                bookClass: '',
                firstStock: '',
                editAmount: '',
                difference: '',
            }, {
                brandName: '',
                titleName: '',
                bookClass: '',
                firstStock: '',
                editAmount: '',
                difference: '',
            }],
            books: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`api/books`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.setState({
                    books: response.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }

    addRow = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                rows: [...prevState.rows, {
                    brandName: '',
                    titleName: '',
                    bookClass: '',
                    firstStock: '',
                    editAmount: '',
                    difference: '',
                }]
            }
        })
    }

    //here where I'm starting to get confused
    handleChange = (index, value) => {
        const rows = [...this.state.rows];
        let awe = JSON.parse(value.key);
        this.setState({
            rows: [{
                brandName: awe.book_name,
                titleName: awe.book_title,
                bookClass: awe.book_class,
                firstStock: awe.book_first_amount,
                editAmount: ? ? ? ? ? ? ? , //what should I get as a value of my input text
                difference: Math.abs(this.state.firstStock - this.state.editAmount),
            }]
        })
    };

    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                  <Table>
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>NO</th>
                              <th>BOOK NAME/th>
                              <th>BOOK TITLE</th>
                              <th>BOOK CLASS</th>
                              <th>FIRST STOCK/th>
                              <th>EDIT AMOUNT/th>
                              <th>DIFFERENCE</th>
                              <th>ACTIONS</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          {this.state.rows.map((row, index) => (
                          <tr key={index}>
                              <td>
                                  {index + 1}
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <Select showSearch labelInValue style={{width: 200}} placeholder="find book" optionFilterProp="children" onChange={this.handleChange} filterOption={(input, option)=> option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
                                      >
                                      {this.state.books.map((data, index) => <Option key={JSON.stringify(data)}>{data.book_name}</Option>)}
                                  </Select>
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  {row.titleName}
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  {row.bookClass}
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  {row.firstStock}
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  <input type="text" name="name" className="form-control" value={row.editAmount} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                  {row.difference}
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                          ))}
                      </tbody>
                  </Table>
                  <button type="button" onClick={this.addRow} className="add-row">
                      +
                  </button>
              </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to use dynamic `setState`. Please if anyone can help

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to what you are doing inside `handleChange` and what you want to do with the `editAmount`? I am confused because you are calling `handleChange` from two places.

Comment: Are you looking for event.target.value? because handleChange for select returns you the event ```handleChange(event) { this.setState({value: event.target.value}); }```. I got lost too. Made a codesandbox and had to give up, if its useful for someone: https://codesandbox.io/s/xj2z1qqzq4

Comment: thanks for replies.. so in my handle change i want to set the titleName value is a title_name ,  bookClass value is a book_class,  firstStock value is a first_stock.. and in my editAmount/realAmount i want to handle the input change(cannot set with e.target.value), and set the difference state as a difference between first stock with real amount (editAmount), i already change the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/3yoxzm4ql5 @Aadi

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/3yoxzm4ql5 here is the codesandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the Codepen code. I have basically split the components for separation of concerns. Please take a look and tell whether that's what you wanted.

The new Codepen link https://codesandbox.io/s/74kvk02421

Comment: No problem! Happy to help! :)